# Database design for compiling records from another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What's the best way to design a table that reference multiple records from another table?

For example, there is a table called diary that stores subjects, descriptions and keywords, then another table called DiaryCompilation for combining all selected records into a book by just referencing the id from the diary.

What's the best way to create the DiaryCompilation?

I was thinking of consisting it into two fields: id, references

where in all selected records are placed in references, but is it a good practice or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<--- Each record is a new entry of diary --->
Diary: ID, Subject, Description, Keywords 

<--- Single record per compilation for summary info --->
DiaryCompilation: ID, Title 

<--- Pages of Diary Compilation --->
DiaryCompilationEntries: DiaryCompilationID, DiaryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Diary and DiaryCompilation would have a 1 to many relationship. Just make sure that the Id in the DairyCompilation is setup as the Primary Key and put a Foreign Key constraint on it so that it ties back to an Id in the Diary table. This will prevent you from deleting a diary and orphaning a record in the DiaryCompilation table. As long as you have a normalized data model you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your fields atomic. Placing several values in `references` field would make it much harder to query and to enforce referential constraints.

A 1:N relationship between parent and child is modeled by migrating parent's primary key **into child**. In your case, this would look something like this:

```
COMPILATION (
    COMPILATION_ID         PK
    -- Other fields...
)

DIARY (
    DIARY_ID               PK
    COMPILATION_ID         FK(COMPILATION)
    SUBJECT
    DESCRIPTION
)

-- Not a good idea to have several keywords in a single field, so we need a separate table for keywords.
DIARY_KEYWORD (
    DIARY_ID               PK, FK(DIARY)
    KEYWORD                PK
)
```

If you actually want N:N relationship (i.e. diary can be part of more than one compilation), you'll need a dedicated table to hold these connections, something like this:

```
COMPILATION (
    COMPILATION_ID         PK
)

DIARY_IN_COMPILATION (
    COMPILATION_ID         PK, FK(COMPILATION)
    DIARY_ID               PK, FK(DIARY)
)

DIARY (
    DIARY_ID PK
    SUBJECT
    DESCRIPTION
)

DIARY_KEYWORD (
    DIARY_ID               PK, FK(DIARY)
    KEYWORD                PK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to create the DiaryCompilation?

Sounds like the *best* way might be to use a view instead of a table.